# how do i can first click changing button image and second click show preview image (first image for button)?

Tags: c#, winforms

how do first click change button image and second click show preview image (first image for button) ? 
for example :
first button image = image 1 
second button image = image 2

in first click change image button to image2 and in next click change to image 1 .

default image for button is image1.

what is mouse events ?

mouse down and ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    int ImageNum = 1;

    private void button1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ImageNum == 1)
        {
            button1.Image = Image2;
            ImageNum = 2;
        }
        else
        {
            button1.Image = Image1;
            ImageNum = 1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if the image of the button equals Image1, if it is, change it to image2, if not, change it to image1.

```
button1.Image = button1.Image == Image2 || button1.Image == null ? Image1 : Image2;
```

This can either be placed in the `Click` event or `MouseClick` event, both will have the same result.

Comment: I am assuming you are loading a new image in your event everytime that is why its not working since then the images are not the same technically.